# Tkinter can't access self labels with bind

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to access tkinter variables from a function, however I am getting the error 
`AttributeError: 'ClassA' object has no attribute 'bet'`

I am using a bind for a label to invoke the function here:

`self.label.bind("<Button-1>", self.calculator(self.teamAOdds[0], self.teamBOdds[1]))`

This is the function:

```
def calculator(self, a, b, ac=0, bc=0):
     betamt = self.bet.get()
     self.betA.insert(END, a)
     self.betB.insert(END, b)
     self.commA.configure(text=ac)
     self.commB.configure(text=bc)
```

For each of these labels which I am trying to access in the function, I get an AttributeError.

If I use a button to invoke a function e.g.

```
self.startButton.configure(command=self.start)
```

Then I can directly access the tkinter labels/entry forms from that function.

Is there any way I can do this for a label bind?

Thanks.

Comment: [Similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767228/why-is-button-parameter-command-executed-when-declared).

Comment: please show a [mcve]